# Show the formula in a view column, not the result of the formula?

Tags: 2007, list-view

Is it possible to have a view which displays the actual column formula, rather than the result of the fomula?

e.g.

Display `"=IF(Foo="Bar".....)"`
and not
`"TRUE"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used the formula below to concatenate information such as document name and version, or to create unique IDs in SharePoint.

You can use formula for showing your formula.

Concatenate your formula with parameters.

For example:

> IF(Foo="Bar".....)

is your formula(F1). And this shows true or false.

Second formula is calculated field and you will only use concatenate with parameters for show

> "IF(Foo="Bar".....)"

as text.